# How do I repair a corrupted system table in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, corruption

I just attempted to do a pg_upgrade on a fairly large PostgreSQL database cluster from version 8.3.0 to version 9.0.4. Everything looked like it was going to work just fine until the new schema was being created on the target cluster. It died trying to create a group role twice for some reason.

After looking at all the scripts, it was quite obvious that it was duplicating a group role 4 times. I brought the 8.3.0 database back up and it was very apparent that there was a row repeated in the `pg_authid` table.

I tried bringing the database up in single-user mode in order to try to `REINDEX TABLE pg_authid`. This failed when trying to create the new index with duplicated values.

I tried deleting the offending group role. This removed one of the 4 rows in `pg_authid`, but just seemed to confuse things further.

I saw mention that running a full vacuum on the table may repair such corruption, but I have little hope of that working. So, while the data restores, I'll fish for ideas.

Comment: You'd better ask in postgresql mailing-lists : http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into modifying pg_upgrade so you can fix the bad statements, as suggested by Sean, before proceeding with the upgrade? I believe a dump/restore is happening in pg_upgrade for system tables.

Comment: Wow, it turns out `pg_upgrade` is easily modified. I just put a pause in the dump.c file before it uses the global dump SQL script. It was easy enough to fix the corruption in there. After that, everything upgraded as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow [`pg_upgrade` steps](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) exactly? If so, you should have your old datadir available and can roll back to it if necessary.... right? :(

A `REINDEX TABLE` won't solve your problem, but a

```
# From old database
pg_dump -t my_problem_table(s) ... > my_screwed_up_data.sql
pg_dump -T my_problem_table(s) ... > my_not_screwed_up_data.sql


# Fix whatever isn't right
${EDITOR} my_screwed_up_data.sql

# In to a fresh database instance
cat my_screwed_up_data.sql | psql
cat my_not_screwed_up_data.sql | psql
```

might get you started. You'll probably have to run steps two and three a few times until you get things loaded correctly. Hopefully it's just your system catalogs that have bogus data.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing any dump/restore operations. I did manage to get all my data in a new database instance by using `pg_dumpall`, editing the dump file and reloading everything into a new database.  This is more or less what you're suggesting and it works fine but it's going to take an insane amount of time to complete this process. I was hoping to do a `pg_upgrade` with the `--link` option in order to keep the upgrade process down to a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Agreed. I'd report this bug if you haven't already. In practice, btw, I normally use `pgbouncer` listening on port 5432 as my way of "pointing" to the right database so that `SELECT`s can go through to a functioning version of the database. It's a very, very nice operational tool.